# Insert HTML in displayNewAppointmentForm Office.js

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I've been working on a Office.js add-in that automatically generates some text depending on a few previously saved settings.  This text is editable.

[image]

I'm using CKEDITOR v4.14 for the rich-text editor. However, when I click "Planlegg møte" (Plan meeting), the text itself is pasted into the displayNewAppointmentForm object as plain-text, HTML tags and all. No conversion is happening. [image]

Upon closing the dialog box, I'm creating the new appointment by caling the following after closing the dialog and before completing the button click event:

```js
dialog.close();
dialog = null;
setTimeout(() => {
  Office.context.mailbox.displayNewAppointmentForm({
     location: 'https://' + settings.data.domain + '.easymeeting.net/' + settings.data.number,
     subject: 'Easymeeting videomøte',
     requiredAttendees: [],
     optionalAttendees: [],
     resources: [Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress],
     body: settings.data.message,
  });
}, 500);
btnEvent.completed();
btnEvent = null;
```

I also tried setting the body by calling Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync after initializing the new appointment form but it seems very little is happening on the Outlook client on PC.

Is it possible to insert a message as HTML or otherwise formatted (with newline "\n" for example) in the displayNewAppointmentForm body?

Comment: Looks like this feature has not been implemented.  Here is the user-voice link for it: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/36314203-adding-html-body-using-displaynewappointmentform

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've gone ahead and put my votes against the features I'd like to see come to Office.js

Answer (score 2):

You are able to use special characters such as `\n` and `\t`, however HTML is not possible today. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins).

It looks like the feature you want has been requested by others already. Please upvote the existing request [`displayNewAppointmentForm`](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/36314203-adding-html-body-using-displaynewappointmentform). Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Thank you so much for the link.  I've gone ahead and put my votes for the features I'd like to see come to this amazing plugin. :) I'll try and play around a bit more with the text formatting.

Comment: This api is still unavailable for HTML format and this link of user-voice page is 404. Does MSFT have any update?