# Outlook: Office.js API Office.context.mailbox.displayNewAppointmentForm API doesn't support body with HTML format

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am writing an Outlook Web based add-in on MessageRead scenario and try to use this API Office.context.mailbox.displayNewAppointmentForm to create a new appointment and insert the content as HTML format.
The sample code in [MSFT document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-mailbox-displaynewappointmentform-member(1)) likes:

```
const start = new Date();
const end = new Date();
end.setHours(start.getHours() + 1);

Office.context.mailbox.displayNewAppointmentForm({
  requiredAttendees: ["bob@contoso.com"],
  optionalAttendees: ["sam@contoso.com"],
  start: start,
  end: end,
  location: "Home",
  subject: "meeting",
  resources: ["projector@contoso.com"],
  body: "Hello World!"
});
```

But when i try to insert:

```
body:'<b>Test Appointment</b><br><br>Test appointment body.'
```

It still show the text but the document states that this parameter can be "AppointmentForm".

Then i search the similar question and found one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61467783/insert-html-in-displaynewappointmentform-office-js) in 2020. MSFT doesn't support it yet.

So, what's the truth of this API? Or is there any workaround for my question?

Answer (score 0):

Executing the code that you've mentioned, with the body set to the HTML string that you have provided gives a reply form like this- which is the exact behaviour as expected (including the html in the appointment body). Is there something different that you need the API to do?:

[image]